# Is there duty to mitigate damages by killing and replacing injured animal instead of curing it?

Tags: damages, tort, new-zealand, animals, damage-mitigation

Say somebody ill-treated my animal which I kept as a pet. It got severely injured. To survive, it had to stay at the veterinary for 2 weeks. The bill was 20x times higher than the market price of the animal.

If I then attempted to claim damages, would my claim be rebuffed on the basis that I should have "mitigated" the costs by just killing the animal and buying a new one?

Comment: I presume you are really looking for specific case law and not just a yes/no opinion.

Comment: @user6726 I was hoping there were some established principles that can be applied here. If none exist then yes, I'll have to dig through case law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things, especially but not only living things, have value beyond the price at which they can be bought and sold - always assuming they *can* be bought and sold. The value of a specific pet cat is not the cost of a generic kitten.

The purpose of damages is to restore you, as far as money can, to the position you were in before the wrong-doers actions occurred. Your duty to mitigate is to do all that is reasonable to minimize the costs - that may mean that you have a duty to choose treatment plan A over treatment plan B if A is cheaper than B and the prognosis is similar - it does not mean you have to choose euthanasia.

The defendant is free to argue that you acted unreasonably but given that vet bills *typically* run to 20x or more the price of a new animal, I don't think they would be successful.

Of course, if the animal were an economic asset, like a farm animal, rather than a pet, then a purely economic outlet may be reasonable.

Comment: What if the defendant could not reasonably foresee that the animal was a pet? Say it was a _duck_ that was a very dear pet to the owner, but was thought as poultry/economic asset by the defendant?

Comment: @Greendrake why would that matter? It is what it is even if the defendant doesn't know what it is.

Comment: I thought it matters because of [reasonable foreseeability](http://www.unistudyguides.com/wiki/Reasonable_foreseeability). There are heaps of cases where defendants were held liable only for what one could expect from their wrongdoing, not for what it actually caused.

Comment: @Greendrake reasonable foreseeability doesn't extend to the quantum of damages but to the foreseeability of the harm.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not getting that. Reasonable foreseeability of the harm _limits_ the quantum of damages the defendant is liable for, doesn't it?

Comment: If you break my vase then it must have been reasonably foreseeable that your actions could break my vase. If my vase is a stylish modern vase you owe me say $100 - if its an original Ming vase you owe me several million dollars - you don't have to foresee that it was a Ming vase.